# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, php7.3, laradock

есть проект на ларавел. написал миграцию и в `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` поставил `;extension=pdo_mysql -> extension=pdo_mysql`. и когда в проекте запускаю `php artisan migrate` выводится такое:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = toph and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

      +33 vendor frames
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException

  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator))

  at Unknown:0
      1▕

      +1 vendor frames
  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

[такой выхлоп](https://pastebin.com/hZ47anp9) у `pvp -m`

upd: я использую laradock. а проект запускаю соотвественно из workspace. так же запущен контейнер php-fpm

upd: уже все перепробовал. ничего не получается. установлен в workspace ОС Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `sudo apt install pdo_mysql`

Comment: @ArchDemon делал. не сработало. так же пробовал php7.3-mysql

Comment: А вы пробовали зайти в контейнер и посмотреть что у вас пыха подгружает? `php -r 'phpinfo()'` как то так вроде